# New privilege: "Star everywhere"

Tags: feature-request, reputation, chat, privileges, chat-stars

I would like to propose a new reputation privilege: "Star Everywhere". The details can still be discussed, but I'm thinking about something like this:

- Users cannot star messages in all chat rooms by default.
- Users gain the ability to star messages in a room by being active (as in, speaking) in the room for several days
- Users with above 1000(?) reputation can star messages in all chat rooms.
- Moderators can obviously star messages in all chat rooms.

This should prevent most star abuse without hurting legitimate room regulars who happen to have low reputation.

Comment: Not very familiar with chat. Is there currently a problem with starring?

Comment: @juergend today, anyone with 20 reputation can walk into a room and star every message on the transcript. Room owners can cancel those stars, one by one. But that takes 2-3 clicks, while starring only takes one.

Comment: @juergend No, there isn't really, people are making more out of stars than there is to it. Still, interesting idea.

Comment: Does this form of star abuse happen in practice? How common is it?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I've seen my share of them. I've seen 3 separate instances today alone and in one room alone, probably due to the hat.